# How to create array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I'm attempting to create an array of objects in php and was curious how I would go about that. Any help would be great, thanks!

Here is the class that will be contained in the array

```
<?php

class hoteldetails {
private $hotelinfo;
private $price;

public function sethotelinfo($hotelinfo){
    $this->hotelinfo=$hotelinfo;
}

public function setprice($price){
    $this->price=$price;
}

public function gethotelinfo(){
    return $hotelinfo;
}

public function getprice(){
    return $price;
}

}
```

And here is what I am attempting to do-

```
<?PHP
include 'file.php';

$hotelsdetail=array();    

$hotelsdetail[0]=new hoteldetails();
$hotelsdetail[0].sethotelinfo($rs);
$hotelsdetail[0].setprice('150');


?>
```

The class attempting to create the array doesn't compile but is just a best guess as to how I can do this. Thanks again

Comment: Use `$hotelsdetail[0]->sethotelinfo($rs);` and `$hotelsdetail[0]->setprice('150');`

Comment: add this in the beginning of your script to get the exact error:
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Answer (score 20):

What you should probably do is:

```
$hotelsDetail = array();

$details = new HotelDetails();
$details->setHotelInfo($rs);
$details->setPrice('150');

// assign it to the array here; you don't need the [0] index then
$hotelsDetail[] = $details;
```

In your specific case, the issue is that you should use `->`, not `.`. The period isn't used in PHP to access attributes or methods of a class:

```
$hotelsdetail[0] = new hoteldetails();
$hotelsdetail[0]->sethotelinfo($rs);
$hotelsdetail[0]->setprice('150');
```

Note that I capitalized the class, object, and function names properly. Writing everything in lowercase is not considered good style.

<sub>As a side note, why is your price a string? It should be a number, really, if you ever want to do proper calculations with it.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this was just something I free handed really quick to explain my problem which is why some of it looks sloppy.

Comment: @BryantJackson While I agree that coding style is subjective, I still believe it should be mentioned, and the OP should – in this case – learn to capitalize instead of writing everything in lowercase. Note that edits such as yours, which are radically changing answers, are discouraged on Stack Overflow. It would have been better if – for such subjective issues – you left a comment, based on which the OP can decide whether (and how) they want to improve their answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should append to your array, not assign to index zero.

```
$hotelsdetail = array();    
$hotelsdetail[] = new hoteldetails();
```

This will append the object to the end of the array.

```
$hotelsdetail = array();    
$hotelsdetail[] = new hoteldetails();
$hotelsdetail[] = new hoteldetails();
$hotelsdetail[] = new hoteldetails();
```

This would create an array with three objects, appending each one successively.

---

Additionally, to correctly access an objects properties, you should use the `->` operator.

```
$hotelsdetail[0]->sethotelinfo($rs);
$hotelsdetail[0]->setprice('150');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array of object by encoding it into json and decoding it with $assoc flag as FALSE in json_decode() function.

See the following example:

```
    $attachment_ids = array();
    $attachment_ids[0]['attach_id'] = 'test';
    $attachment_ids[1]['attach_id'] = 'test1';
    $attachment_ids[2]['attach_id'] = 'test2';
    $attachment_ids                 = json_encode($attachment_ids);
    $attachment_ids                 = json_decode($attachment_ids, FALSE);
    print_r($attachment_ids);
```

It would render an array of objects.

output:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attach_id] => test
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attach_id] => test1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attach_id] => test2
    )

)
```