# How to sort an Array using If in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following `Array` which contains data such as: *Card, Month and Year*. However, I receive it in a disorganized way and I would like to treat these values to follow the pattern. No *Card, Year and Month* or *Month, Card and Year*. I tried to use the `sort()` functions of php, but without success!

```
Array                                                                                                                    (
[0] => Array 
(
    [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
    [1] => 2020
    [2] => 09
)

[1] => Array 
(
    [0] => 09
    [1] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
    [2] => 2020
)

[2] => Array 
(
    [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 9
)                                                                                                    
)
```

I would like to create a function in which the Array is organized as follows:

```
 Array                                                                                                                   (
    [0] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 09
        [2] => 2020
    )

    [1] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 09
        [2] => 2020
    )

    [2] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 20
    )
)
```

Then comes the point of conditions, if as the `Array` the year 2020 is defined with only **2** decimal places, that is, 20 (19, 20, 21, 22, 23, ...) I would check if the value does not is greater than 12, following the number of months we have in 1 year, knowing this, to identify the year in this `Array`, I would apply another validation to check if the value is greater than 12 and if it has 2 or 4 digits, however I can't apply it in any way!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Better to store these values as objects. Then store those objects in an array or list. Then, you wouldn't have to worry about the index of data inside the object.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _No Card, Year and Month or Month, Card and Year_ ? As I see it, its just card, month and then year.

Comment: @Loki how could i do it this way in php?

Comment: @nice_dev I would like to organize the Array, because after organizing it, I would transform it into JSON.

Comment: PHP is not really my field, but these are the links I found that may help you: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174228/how-to-create-array-of-objects-in-php/45940619

Comment: can possible in case yesr will come in 4 digit. otherwise not possible

Comment: @Loki old man, thank you very much i will go deeper, any news return here!

Comment: @GleidsonJdeLima I do know you want to but I asked a different question.

Comment: problem is year coming in 2 digits as well (what I saw in your code example), which makes it impossible to find-out via condition : because 12 can be 2012 year and 12 can be month as well

Comment: @AlivetoDie As I mentioned for Wajid, as it is valid, that is, month and year, in the key for the month: 09 (September) follows the pattern, which would be 12 months, values above that with 2 or 4 digits I can consider as the year, already in the month I could create a validation that checks the first digit of the value and check if it starts with 0 or 1 (using two decimal places) and if that value would not be greater than 12, so the use of If's, however , I'm not able to apply this in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment you can go with this solution:

```
$finalArray = [];
foreach($array as $key=>$arr){
    $arry = [];
    foreach($arr as $ar){
        
        if(strlen($ar) > 4){
            $arry[0] = $ar;
        }else if((strlen($ar) ==1 || strlen($ar) == 2) && (int)$ar <=12){
            $arry[1] = $ar;
        }else{
            $arry[2] = $ar;
        }
    }
    ksort($arry);
    $finalArray[$key] = $arry;
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/BZIFX

Comment: What about the card having month 11 and year 11 ?
Your code will fail in that condition.

Comment: It will not fail because of the API it receives, only from the year 2015 upwards, so there is no risk of failure, as it is a validation of credit / debit card

Comment: @JohnDoe  I have already said first that it's like to be impossible to do it , but after reading all comment of OP i came up with this solution. Now it's OP's duty to check it and in case failed then let me know.

Comment: Hmmm Okay. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by comparing the number of values in the array then assign them the index position by going through the loop within the array.

But there is an issue.

```
[0] => Array 
(
    [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 20
)
```

According to your scenario, at one point you are showing 2020 as 20. So this can be possible that it can be a date too as I mentioned the above array. So by using this approach every logic will become failed.

Comment: Good as it is about validities, that is, month and year, in the key referring to the month: 09 (September) follows the pattern, which would be 12 months, values above that with 2 or 4 digits I can consider as the year, already the month I could create a validation that verifies the first digit of the value and check if it starts with 0 or 1 (using two decimal places) and if that value would not be greater than 12, that's why the use of If's, however I'm not managing to apply this in any way